# DataSnapXE2 has bugs , DataSnap2010 is okay

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-xe2, datasnap, c++builder-xe2

With c++builder XE2 there are problems :

When the client has two connections to the application server, 1st connection or 2nd connection disconnected, and the servermethods class is destroy

With c++builder 2010 every thing is okay (I use PatchCppRTTI to expose the servermethods) and i can made the one client instance to make multi connections to 2010 app server and keep every servermethods class wich created in app server works fine ( I need this multi to process multi database at the same time, it is important)

With c++builderXE2 the problem is appeared with no clear reasons, is it bug !?

or something to do in runtime !?

Note : the problems is also appears on IDE .

if any one try to create default simple datasnap application server, and try to connect to it in IDE (e.g.) with two connections and make methods calls in the two connections, any one will see the problem (1st or 2nd connection will make the servermethods class destroy in server)

I trace and monitor every thing, to make very sure thats there is a problem in DataSnapXE2